# The element type 'Set<FutureBuilder<List<CameraDescription>>>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter

When I try to return following from a Widget `build` function:

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: _future,
        builder: (context, snapshot){
          return Stack(
            children: [
              if (_isPermissionGranted){

                FutureBuilder<List<CameraDescription>>(
                  future: availableCameras(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      _initCameraController(snapshot.data!);
                      return Center(child: CameraPreview(_cameraController!));
                    } else {
                      return const LinearProgressIndicator();
                    }
                  },
                ),
              }
            ],
          );
        }
    );
```

it shows following error:
`The element type 'Set<FutureBuilder<List<CameraDescription>>>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.`

But when I remove the curly brackets after the condition `if (_isPermissionGranted)`, the error goes away. Feel free to share any ideas why that is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping something in curly brackets is the way to initialize a `Set`, so that's why. The `if` you use there is not a normal `if` but a so called "collection if" and is always used without curly brackets, and considers the thing behind it as a single object. You can read more about this "collection if" here: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lists

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```dart
FutureBuilder(
  future: _future,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        if (_isPermissionGranted)
          FutureBuilder<List<CameraDescription>>(
            future: availableCameras(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                _initCameraController(snapshot.data!);
                return Center(child: CameraPreview(_cameraController!));
              } else {
                return const LinearProgressIndicator();
              }
            },
          ),
      ],
    );
  },
);
```